# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing input commands

Tags: python, input, syntax

Today I was writing this program

```
from random import randint

def practice():
    command = input("Welcome to math practice! Type mult tables to practice multiplication tables, or simp add for single digit addition")
    if command == "mult tables":
        while True:
            first_value_x = randint(2, 12)
            second_value_x = randint(2, 12)
            number_x = int(input("%s x %s" % (first_value_x, second_value_x )))
            if number_x == first_value_x * second_value_x:
                print("Correct!!")
            else:
                print("You did not get the answer correct.")
    elif command == "simp add":
        while True:
            first_value_simp_add = randint(1,9)
            second_value_simp_add = randint(1,9)
            number_simple_add = int(input("What is %s + %s" %(first_value_simp_add, second_value_simp_add)))
            if number_simple_add == first_value_simp_add + second_value_simp_add:
                print("Well done!")
            else:
                print("You did not the answer correct")
    else:
        print("The command you entered does not exist. Please retype a command")
        practice()

practice()
```

However, I keep getting this error

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

or more specifically

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/student/Desktop/math practice.py", line 49, in <module>
    practice()
  File "/Users/student/Desktop/math practice.py", line 6, in practice
    command = input("Welcome to math practice! Type mult tables to     practice multiplication tables, or simp add for single digit addition")
  File "<string>", line 1
    simp add
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/student/Desktop/math practice.py", line 49, in <module>
    practice()
  File "/Users/student/Desktop/math practice.py", line 6, in practice
    command = input("Welcome to math practice! Type mult tables to practice multiplication tables, or simp add for single digit addition")
  File "<string>", line 1
    mult tables
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

When I try to enter the `mult tables` or `simp add` commands in the input.

I have relooked over my code many times and read a bunch of other `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` threads, yet still cannot find where I went wrong. Sorry if its obvious I'm very new to this kind of stuff. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running your code under Python 2, whose `input()` function returns the result of applying the `eval()` function to the string you enter. I believe the errors will disappear if you instead use the `raw_input()` function. this simply returns the string you enter. See below for more detail.

```
>>> input("Value: ")
Value: 3
3
>>> k = 42
>>> input("Value: ")
Value: k
42
>>> raw_input("Value: ")
Value: k
'k'
>>> input("Value: ")
Value: some random string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    some random string
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Ok thank you!! I guess I just screwed up the python interpreter somehow I assumed it was on python 3. Ill have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2.7 (or anything earlier than Python 3), you need to change your **input(...)** command to use **raw_input(...)**.  I made that change, and it works fine thereafter.

Comment: Don't understand why somebody has downvoted this answer, which seems perfectly justifiable

Comment: I don't know, either.  However, note that someone down-voted the other answer, also.  If you click on the '0' there, you can see both up- and down-votes.

Comment: Some people are just weird.

Comment: If it bugs you; supply up-votes.  Moving on to other issues is likely a better use of personal resources.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, you are using the `input()` function. You can either

- Use Python 3 or higher

  - Update your editor (Are you using the standard editor or visual studio or what else?)
  - Download a new editor such as standard [Python 3+](https://python.org/) or [Anaconda](https://anaconda.com/)
- use the `raw_input()` function  if you are using Python 2 (will ***not*** work in Python 3+):

```
>>> input('Enter a value: ') #Basic input function
Enter a value: 3
3
>>> print('That worked fine.')
That worked fine
>>> var = 42
>>> input('Var: ') '''Will give the value of that variable:
       basically runs print(input) on the input'''
Var: var
42
>>> raw_input('Var: ')
Var: var
'var'
```

(It is similar to what the first post said)