# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (python blockchain)

Tags: python, parsing, eof, blockchain

What I'm trying to do is to iterate over all blocks in blockchain and print out the transactions.
Here is my code so far:

```
from chainscan import iter_blocks
for block in iter_blocks():
    if block.height > 10: break
    for tx in block.txs:
        print('Hello, tx %s in block %s' % (tx, block))
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-06037b89d550>", line 1
    for block in iter_blocks():
                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I already read similar topics like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800511/syntaxerror-unexpected-eof-while-parsing-input-commands) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428447/unexpected-eof-while-parsing-in-python-random-sentence-generator), but they weren't helpful. Is the problem maybe that the blockchain itself isn't found yet by the block iterator? If it is the case, how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: that seems like a non-reproduceable error. the code looks fine

Comment: got it even after a restart

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you indentation is off. Just copy-paste the following code, and it should work:

```
from chainscan import iter_blocks
for block in iter_blocks():
    if block.height > 10: break
    for tx in block.txs:
        print('Hello, tx %s in block %s' % (tx, block))
```